# Erro no Django - Unicode Decode Error

Tags: python, django, unicode

Ao tentar criar uma App em Django com o comando `django-admin.py startapp Name`, tal comando levanta o seguinte erro :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/startapp.py", line 29, in handle
    super(Command, self).handle('app', app_name, target, **options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 162, in handle
    if new_path.endswith(extensions) or filename in extra_files:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Eu tenho de remover esse `0xc3` ? ou tem algum modo de fazer com que ele decodifique ?

**Django 1.11**

Caminhos em que testei:

`/home/bezerk/Área de Trabalho/Blogger`

`/home/bezerk/Downloads`

Pesquisei no Stf, porém em grande parte das vezes a pergunta estava em outro contexto, não no de Djando ( Mas sim no de emoji e coisas do tipo )

Comment: Isso acontece em todos os projetos que vc cria? Se criar um projeto novo, sem nenhum codigo e logo depois criar uma app, tb acontece?

Comment: Será que não tem a ver com a pasta que você está tentando iniciar o projeto? Posta o caminho dela pra gente aí

Comment: Sim, em todos os projetos, adicionei os caminhos ao corpo da pergunta para uma melhor visualização.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Django runserver não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220711/django-runserver-n%c3%a3o-funciona)

Comment: ' Possível duplicata ' ?! - Eu perguntei antes *******, além disso o erro não é no `run server` pois eu verifiquei o nome ( Por essa [tabela](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~rodolfo/aedsi-2-10/Variavel/AsciiTable.png) )

Comment: Pq vc perguntou primeiro não deixa de ser possível duplicata de uma já respondida, eheheh!. Vc tentou executar runserver explicitando o ip e porta do servidor, como sugerido [nessa resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220716/7412) No Stress! :-)

Comment: Ha ha, eu disse que : ' o erro não é no run server ', pois o mesmo está antes, precisamente na criação da aplicação, é impossível que eu teste os itens ditos na [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220711/django-runserver-n%C3%A3o-funciona/220716#220716)  pois nem a aplicação ainda foi gerada por causa do erro ( Obs : Meu ' Sress ' é pouco perto das respostas carinhosas que já recebi, mesmo pesquisando e formatando bem a pergunta ^ -  ^ )

Comment: Provavelmente,deve ser algo relacionado à pastas com acentos...
EX: /HOME/andrÉ/
se vôce tiver algo assim,retire

Comment: Meu user name é ' akira '.