# Django runserver não funciona

Tags: python, django, cgi

**O comando:** python manage.py runserver 80

**Retorna o seguinte:**  (Pus screenshot, pois o texto fica desfigurado aqui)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O endereço localhost fica inacessível, independentemente da porta (8080, 8000, 80)

Pelo que entendi, é um erro de charset/encode, mas não achei solução para ele.

Comment: Para não "desfigurar" a mensagem, basta coloca-la em formato de código.

Comment: @Sidon Eu tentei e deu na mesma, daí, enviei o screenshot.

Comment: Acredito que deva ser algo do próprio django, eu estou com o mesmo erro pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219916/erro-no-django-unicode-decode-error?noredirect=1#comment451593_219916 ( Adicione o código para uma melhor indexação, no lugar de imagem )

Comment: @Walter Veja a resposta do Sidon. Eu mudei o nome do computador e funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está parecendo ser um [bug conhecido do python](http://bugs.python.org/issue9377), em que o runserver falha quando o nome da máquina contém caracteres "non-ASCII", tente uma das duas alternativas:

1) Chame runserver explicitando a porta e o host:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

**Ou:**

2) Mude o nome do computador para uma string que contenha somente
    caracteres ASCII.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado, Sidon!